# Fixed Footer Below Div on Horz Scrolling Website

Tags: css, scroll, footer, fixed

I have a site with this basic markup -->

Header (fixed position)
  Content Area (598px high) - Horiz scrolling, generally around 5000px wide
  Footer

I need for the footer to sit BELOW the content area but to also stay fixed positioned center in the browser like the header. An example of what we want is here:  http://www.woodberrykitchen.com

This is the site we are working on:  http://starprovisions.com/dev/bacchanalia.html

Can anyone help? Is it possible to have the footer div sit below (not cover up) the content area but also stay fixed positioned?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this directly in the browser and it worked just fine.

```
#footer {position: fixed; width: 100%;}
#footer table {margin: auto;}
```

It seems you're fiddling with the site as we discuss it. As of 18:58 GMT+1, you should remove the `height` declaration from `#container`.

Comment: It is still scrolling horizontally: http://starprovisions.com/dev/bacchanalia.html   Is there a way to keep it fixed always below the content that scrolls left to right?

Comment: Oops, must not have had it saved. It is now fixed position but I can't see it in my window and it is left aligned. Is there a way to center it on the screen and to get a vertically scroll bar to show up?

Comment: I edited my answer. Furthermore, there's a lot that I would change in the structure in order for it to work properly on most screen sizes, though I think you need to dig a bit deeper with it yourself first.

Comment: You are such a great help. Thank you! My only issue now is, on my screen (1360x768), I cannot see the footer. I only see the top of it and cannot scroll vertically. How can I allow for a scroll bar to appear so that I can scroll up and down on the whole site?